# Asp.net Dynamic ashx Stylesheet not always working on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, ashx, stylesheet

Help.  I have a site when the customers can add their own style rules to their websites.  The whole process works perfectly, but when they page with the dynamic stylesheet posts back, sometimes only some of the stylesheet rules load.  The initial page loads all of the styles, and some postbacks it loads fine as well, but on some of the postbacks (about 60%) certain styles randomly get dropped.  Is it a lifecycle issue?  Its so random, I have nothing to trace.  Is there a way to load the dynamically generated stylesheet and persist it throughout the session, then dismiss it?

Thanks!!!  The answers I get here always are spot on, someone has got to know whats going on.

Comment: What do you see in Firebug and Fiddler?

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand right the CSS file is there but only some of the rules are being applied?  Are you sure there are no other stylesheets after the one the user uploads that are conflicting/overriding the users' sheet?

Have you been looking in Firebug at all to see what sheets are loaded and where the styles that are being overridden are getting their styles from?

Comment: Yes, the correct sheet is loaded, and the styles are loading properly.  Firebug shows the proper styles, but they arent being applied (randomly) in both ie and firefox.  It seems like the page is sending the correct styles, but the browser is loading to fast and skipping them. Interesting side note.  If I just go to the page, and navigate, they are applied, it only seems to not work when I refresh the page. (Also its not just my system)

Comment: so when you navigate straight there it works, but on refresh it doesnt?  if you were to refresh over and over again would it ever fix itself or is it permanently foobared?  the refresh causing issues is interesting and makes me think that maybe caching could be causing some issues, but its tough to say without knowing more about the setup you have.

Comment: For some reason when I added the head to a user control and cached it, everything is perfect now.